# Using existing Angularjs modules in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

We have an application built in Angularjs(a library module written in angular 1.4 & used my multiple apps).

Our latest apps are being built on Angular2 with typescript. I would like to know if I can make use of the modules(& their directives etc) existing angularjs library in my Angular2 app as is.

Or is there an upgrade/migration process which needs to performed on the AngularJS app to make it compatible with Angular2.

From what I understand, Angular2 is a complete rewrite & not compatible with AngularJS. I referred the [Angular upgrade guide](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade), but it speaks more of upgrading from angularJS to Angular2 than use of existing angularJS modules as is.

Comment: I worked with both angularjs and angular 2+. As you already saw, it is complete rewritten. Because of that, if there would be any application to convert the code, I think it would cost a lot of bugs. The whole architecture is different.

Comment: Is there a way to simply wrap up these AngularJS modules in a Angular 2 understandable way. Rewriting the existing component completely is a kill for me. Is upgrading the only way out?

Comment: Normally when you start a project you should stick with those technologies you started with. I usually don't even upgrade packages. Upgrading from angular 1 to angular 2 is like changing the framework used, since it's another framework. That should be done only if you really have big advantages and you want to rewrite the whole application. Ask yourself if you really need what angular 2 offers and angular 1 does not.